# Array not repeating inside in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I have an array for autofilled multi select form. I have to display some values as initial values, And I have an array for it.
This is my code.

```
 for($i=0; $i<count($temp_multy_name); $i++)
 {

     echo  $temp_multy_name[$i]; echo"&nbsp";
     $pac->set_init_selection(array(
        array("id"=>"$temp_multy_name[$i]", "text"=>"$temp_multy_name[$i]"),
     ));

 }
```

when I run `echo $temp_multy_name[$i]`, i get php and mysql, but when I apply it in the `set_init_selection` i got only the last value, Don't know why. Can any one please help me?

[image]

Comment: How does this relate to JavaScript? All I'm seeing is PHP.

Comment: Please explaint what you mean when you say: *but when I apply it in the set_init_selection i got only the last value,*

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution

```
  $setInitSelection = array();
  for($i=0; $i<count($temp_multy_name); $i++)
  {

     echo  $temp_multy_name[$i]; echo"&nbsp";
     $setInitSelection[] = array("id"=>$temp_multy_name[$i], "text"=>$temp_multy_name[$i]);

  } 
  $pac->set_init_selection($setInitSelection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are overriding your array. Try this:

```
$selection_array = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($temp_multy_name); $i++)
{
    //echo  $temp_multy_name[$i]; echo"&nbsp";
    $selection_array[] = array("id"=>$temp_multy_name[$i], "text"=>$temp_multy_name[$i]);
} 

$pac->set_init_selection($selection_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your calling the $pac->set_init_name(array $val) multiple times, overwriting the previous values. Try this:

```
$initialSelection = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($temp_multy_name); $i++)
  {
     echo  $temp_multy_name[$i]; echo"&nbsp";
     $initialSelection[$i] = array("id"=>$temp_multy_name[$i], "text"=>$temp_multy_name[$i]);
  } 

  $pac->set_init_selection(array($initialSelection);
```

Hope that helps.